# C++ printf with %f but localized for the user's country

Tags: c++, windows, locale, printf, string-formatting

I'm using the following C++ syntax to output a floating point value on a Windows platform:

```
printf("%.2f", 1.5);
```

It works well if I run it on an English user account. My assumption was that if I run it on, say French user account, the output will be 1,50 instead of 1.50.

Why do I not see it and how to produce my desired result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The radix character (i.e. '.' or ',') is defined by the current locale. The default locale (at least for Windows systems) is "C", which defines '.' as radix character.

You can set the current locale for a C/C++ program using the `setlocale` function.

To set the locale to the current system/user locale, you can use the following statement:

```
#include <locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".OCP");
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (cf. the examples on the linked page...) for more information about `setlocale`

Comment: Thanks, but when am I supposed to call setlocale -- at the beginning when the app initializes or before every printf?

Comment: It is sufficient to call it once at the beginning of your app.

Comment: The C++ alternative is `std::cout.imbue( std::locale("") );`

Comment: @MSalters You can also set the global locale in C++; newly created streams will be constructed with the current global locale.  You'll still need `imbue` for the standard streams, however, since these will have been created before you get to main.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setlocale() function
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/