# C/C++: printf use commas instead of dots as decimal separator

Tags: c, decimal, printf

I need that my program shows the output using commas as decimal separator.

According to this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Floatingpointwithcommasf.htm you can use in Java something like this:

```
System.out.printf("Floating-point with commas: %,f\n", 1234567.123);
```

Is there a flag or something that I can use to have a similar behaviour in C?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That'll be a duplicate of this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684014/c-printf-with-f-but-localized-for-the-users-country

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ printf with %f but localized for the user's country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684014/c-printf-with-f-but-localized-for-the-users-country)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want, you can set current locale at the beginning of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "French_Canada.1252"); // ".OCP" if you want to use system settings
    printf("%f\n", 3.14543);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Similarly, `const struct lconv* loc = localeconv();` can be used to get locale specifics. From there you can check `loc->decimal_point[0]` to see which decimal separator that is currently used.

Comment: also you may get current locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);` to restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

There is no similar functionality in `C`. You can use `sprintf` to print into a char array and then replace the dot with a comma manually. I can't think of a better solution, sorry.

EDIT:  thanks to Mats Patersson's comment:
It seems setting the locale can change this character. Please have a look at the link he posted.

Comment: +1 - I think your answer was better than mine, as locale may be the correct fix.