# format value type float in (Programming Language C/C++)

Tags: c++, c

How show 00156,00

```
float number = 156;
printf("%5.2f",number);
```

The output of the example above:

Output: 156.00

Comment: C or C++, pick one because the answer will depend on the language.

Comment: The reason it printed 6 characters not the 5 requested is that this format does not break the value supplied. With 2 decimal places the value cannot be printed with 5 characters.

Comment: Is this a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753505/c-c-printf-use-commas-instead-of-dots-as-decimal-separator) or of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684014/c-printf-with-f-but-localized-for-the-users-country)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing leading 0's in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `0` flag for leading zeros, and the field width must be wide enough to have any leading characters printed.  So you might try this:

```
printf("%08.2f", number);
```

The `.` verses `,` (aka, the "radix character") is determined from the LC_NUMERIC portion of the locale.  See `man setlocale` for information on setting this programatically.